# Socket programming chat application

Tags: c, sockets, port, chat, ip-address

I made a chat application using sockets in c language. When i run server and client on same device it works fine. But, when i run client and server on different device client shows connect error. is this problem related to ip address.

server side code:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define MAX_CLIENTS 100
#define BUFFER_SZ 2048

static _Atomic unsigned int cli_count = 0;
static int uid = 10;

/* Client structure */
typedef struct{
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int sockfd;
    int uid;
    char name[32];
} client_t;

client_t *clients[MAX_CLIENTS];

pthread_mutex_t clients_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void str_overwrite_stdout() {
    printf("\r%s", "> ");
    fflush(stdout);
}

void str_trim_lf (char* arr, int length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { // trim \n
    if (arr[i] == '\n') {
      arr[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
}

void print_client_addr(struct sockaddr_in addr){
    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d",
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff00) >> 8,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff0000) >> 16,
        (addr.sin_addr.s_addr & 0xff000000) >> 24);
}

/* Add clients to queue */
void queue_add(client_t *cl){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(!clients[i]){
            clients[i] = cl;
            break;
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}

/* Remove clients to queue */
void queue_remove(int uid){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i < MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(clients[i]){
            if(clients[i]->uid == uid){
                clients[i] = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}

/* Send message to all clients except sender */
void send_message(char *s, int uid){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&clients_mutex);

    for(int i=0; i<MAX_CLIENTS; ++i){
        if(clients[i]){
            if(clients[i]->uid != uid){
                if(write(clients[i]->sockfd, s, strlen(s)) < 0){
                    perror("ERROR: write to descriptor failed");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&clients_mutex);
}

/* Handle all communication with the client */
void *handle_client(void *arg){
    char buff_out[BUFFER_SZ];
    char name[32];
    int leave_flag = 0;

    cli_count++;
    client_t *cli = (client_t *)arg;

    // Name
    if(recv(cli->sockfd, name, 32, 0) <= 0 || strlen(name) <  2 || strlen(name) >= 32-1){
        printf("Didn't enter the name.\n");
        leave_flag = 1;
    } else{
        strcpy(cli->name, name);
        sprintf(buff_out, "%s has joined\n", cli->name);
        printf("%s", buff_out);
        send_message(buff_out, cli->uid);
    }

    bzero(buff_out, BUFFER_SZ);

    while(1){
        if (leave_flag) {
            break;
        }

        int receive = recv(cli->sockfd, buff_out, BUFFER_SZ, 0);
        if (receive > 0){
            if(strlen(buff_out) > 0){
                send_message(buff_out, cli->uid);

                str_trim_lf(buff_out, strlen(buff_out));
                printf("%s -> %s\n", buff_out, cli->name);
            }
        } else if (receive == 0 || strcmp(buff_out, "exit") == 0){
            sprintf(buff_out, "%s has left\n", cli->name);
            printf("%s", buff_out);
            send_message(buff_out, cli->uid);
            leave_flag = 1;
        } else {
            printf("ERROR: -1\n");
            leave_flag = 1;
        }

        bzero(buff_out, BUFFER_SZ);
    }

  /* Delete client from queue and yield thread */
    close(cli->sockfd);
  queue_remove(cli->uid);
  free(cli);
  cli_count--;
  pthread_detach(pthread_self());

    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *ip = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);
    int option = 1;
    int listenfd = 0, connfd = 0;
  struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
  struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
  pthread_t tid;

  /* Socket settings */
  listenfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  serv_addr.sin_port = htons(port);

  /* Ignore pipe signals */
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

    if(setsockopt(listenfd, SOL_SOCKET,(SO_REUSEPORT | SO_REUSEADDR),(char*)&option,sizeof(option)) < 0){
        perror("ERROR: setsockopt failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    /* Bind */
  if(bind(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: Socket binding failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  /* Listen */
  if (listen(listenfd, 10) < 0) {
    perror("ERROR: Socket listening failed");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("=== WELCOME TO THE CHATROOM ===\n");

    while(1){
        socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);
        connfd = accept(listenfd, (struct sockaddr*)&cli_addr, &clilen);

        /* Check if max clients is reached */
        if((cli_count + 1) == MAX_CLIENTS){
            printf("Max clients reached. Rejected: ");
            print_client_addr(cli_addr);
            printf(":%d\n", cli_addr.sin_port);
            close(connfd);
            continue;
        }

        /* Client settings */
        client_t *cli = (client_t *)malloc(sizeof(client_t));
        cli->address = cli_addr;
        cli->sockfd = connfd;
        cli->uid = uid++;

        /* Add client to the queue and fork thread */
        queue_add(cli);
        pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &handle_client, (void*)cli);

        /* Reduce CPU usage */
        sleep(1);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

client side code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define LENGTH 2048

// Global variables
volatile sig_atomic_t flag = 0;
int sockfd = 0;
unsigned char name[32];

void str_overwrite_stdout() {
  printf("%s", "> ");
  fflush(stdout);
}

void str_trim_lf (char* arr, int length) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) { // trim \n
    if (arr[i] == '\n') {
      arr[i] = '\0';
      break;
    }
  }
}

void catch_ctrl_c_and_exit(int sig) {
    flag = 1;
}

void send_msg_handler() {
  unsigned char message[LENGTH] = {};
    unsigned char buffer[3000] = {};

  while(1) {
    str_overwrite_stdout();
    fgets(message, LENGTH, stdin);
    str_trim_lf(message, LENGTH);

    if (strcmp(message, "exit") == 0) {
            break;
    } else {
      sprintf(buffer, "%s: %s\n", name, message);
      send(sockfd, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
    }

        bzero(message, LENGTH);
    bzero(buffer, LENGTH + 32);
  }
  catch_ctrl_c_and_exit(2);
}

void recv_msg_handler() {
    char message[LENGTH] = {};
  while (1) {
        int receive = recv(sockfd, message, LENGTH, 0);
    if (receive > 0) {
      printf("%s", message);
      str_overwrite_stdout();
    } else if (receive == 0) {
            break;
    } else {
            // -1
        }
        memset(message, 0, sizeof(message));
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Usage: %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    char *ip = "152.168.0.100";
    int port = atoi(argv[1]);

    signal(SIGINT, catch_ctrl_c_and_exit);

    printf("Please enter your name: ");
  fgets(name, 32, stdin);
  str_trim_lf(name, strlen(name));


    if (strlen(name) > 32 || strlen(name) < 2){
        printf("Name must be less than 30 and more than 2 characters.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    /* Socket settings */
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);
  server_addr.sin_port = htons(port);


  // Connect to Server
  int err = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
  if (err == -1) {
        printf("ERROR: connect\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Send name
    send(sockfd, name, 32, 0);

    printf("=== WELCOME TO THE CHATROOM ===\n");

    pthread_t send_msg_thread;
  if(pthread_create(&send_msg_thread, NULL, (void *) send_msg_handler, NULL) != 0){
        printf("ERROR: pthread\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    pthread_t recv_msg_thread;
  if(pthread_create(&recv_msg_thread, NULL, (void *) recv_msg_handler, NULL) != 0){
        printf("ERROR: pthread\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (1){
        if(flag){
            printf("\nBye\n");
            break;
    }
    }

    close(sockfd);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

it is showing connect error when i run it on different machines.

Comment: You will have to provide more information. Otherwise the answers will more or less be "you probably have a mistake somewhere in your code".

Comment: Server IP should be 0.0.0.0 rather than 127.0.0.1

Comment: what do you mean by different device? Are the two devices on the same subnet? Meaning: are they connected to the same router?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as I can tell, the codes that you posted are incomplete, but let's assume that, as you say, everything is working fine, it work in the local machine, but when you run the two programs in two different devices, the client fails to connect to the server.

Then I would ask you the question, as I also asked it in the comment: are the two devices in the same subnet? You have a home router, and both devices are connected to this router?

If not, then that will be the problem. I am not sure how deep you understand IP addresses and subnets, but here is a simple summary. When you look at the IP address on your PC, you see your private IP address that was given you by the router. Let's say, that you have two machines connected to the same router, one has the IP address of 192.168.0.101, the other 192.168.0.102. If 192.168.0.101 is the client and wants to connect to the server that runs on 192.168.0.102, it should work without problems.

But let's say that you send the server code to me. I run the server on my computer, which has the IP address of 192.168.0.103, you still run the client at home on 192.168.0.101. In this case, you won't be able to connect to my machine, because the 192.168.0.103 is the private IP address given out by my own router. For that to work, I would have to at least configure my router to open up a port and forward the packets coming to that port to my PC. Then I would have to give you the public IP and the port. And so if the firewall is configured so that it allows your packets into my network, then it might work.

Of course it is a bit more complicated than this, but this is the general idea.

If this is not the case for you, and the devices are on the same subnet, then we would simply need more information and the comlete code.